# JavaScript - Calling the click function more than once would not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a text adventure game, which would require user input in the form of a  element in html, which would send the user input to JavaScript using the click function:

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->
<div class="game">
    <div id="gamebox">
        <a name="game"></a>
        <!-- Javascript writes to here (if it works :( ) -->
    </div>
    <div id="inputbox">
        <input type="text" id="userinput" placeholder="Input" value="" />
        <a href="#game" id="btn-quest" class="button" style="float: right">Go!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see above, I have a  element and a "Go!" button, which sends it to my JavaScript code. In JavaScript, first I define 3 variables where I would output my text.

```
//JavaScript Code

var txt_input = $("#userinput");
var btn_quest = $("#btn-quest");
```

I would than define 2 other functions, which allows me to write into the . I would than have other functions, which are for the storyline of the text adventure game. However, the root of the problem is that I can't seem to progress past the second event. Here are my events:

```
function wakeUp() {
  displayGame("You wake up, at stackoverflow. West or east? [Choose 'west' or 'east']");
  btn_quest.on({
    "click": function() {
      // Begin input preproccessing
      var input = txt_input.val().toLowerCase();
      // If/else block for choice here
      if (input === "west") {
        //Paste btn_quest here for new event
        goWest();
      } else if (input === "east") {
        //Paste btn_quest here for new event
        goEast();
      } else {
        //Error handler - do not modify
        txt_input.val("Error - enter a valid choice");
      }
    //End of if else block body
    }
  });
```

The first event function would work perfectly, and write to my html, and accept the first user choice. However, at the next event, no matter what it is, (goEast() or goWest()), my program aways displays "Error - enter a valid choice"). Right now, my hypothesis is that the "switch" function isn't working correctly. However, I honestly don't know. What is the issue here, and how can I fix it? The other event functions (etc goEast) are exactly the same as the wakeUp function, except with different displayGame() strings and link to other event functions.

I have not included the full code, in order to keep my code short - but here is the full html/css/javascript if needed: http://plnkr.co/edit/55heHh4k5QEIVYdBrWGB?p=preview

Edit: I tried to implement the suggestion, like this: But It seems that JavaScript doesn't even get the userinput anymore. When I try to submit the user's response, nothing happens. What went wrong? I did the same thing here with all of my functions in the game:

```
function wakeUp() {
  displayGame("You wake up at stackoverflow again, but it didn't work. Go West or east again?");
  // btn_quest.off("click").on("click",function()){
  btn_quest.off("click").on;
    "click", function() {
      // Begin input preproccessing
      var input = txt_input.val().toLowerCase();
      // If/else block for choice here
      if (input === "walk") {
        //Paste btn_quest here for new event
        walkToWork();
      } else if (input === "bus") {
        //Paste btn_quest here for new event
        busToWork();
      } else {
        //Error handler - do not modify
        txt_input.val("Error - enter a valid choice");
      }
    //End of if else block body
  };
  //End of function. Copy until line under this comment V
}
```

What did I do wrong? Can you please show a example using this function?

Comment: hmmm... wouldn't the first event be, going east or west? or are you considering `wakeUp` an event

Comment: If `goEast` and `goWest` are exactly the same as `wakeUp`, does that mean they also bind a click event to the same button, resulting in multiple click events?

Comment: I don't understand, but yes. They are all binded to the same button on the html, and when the input is sent over to the javascript, the page does not refresh. Also, yes, the first function should be goingEastOrWest() - I just forgot to change the name from the original function, where the main character wakes up. I removed much of my code so it's short and to the point, and I can post them on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at all the code to see the problem. The reason is because you keep binding to the element so multiple click events are being triggered. You need to remove the last click

```
btn_quest.off("click").on("click",function(){});
```

Comment: I'm rather new to programming, so let me tell you what I understand: Basically, the button is like a switch, and after turning it on, I would have to turn it back off again, before trying to turn it on again. Is that correct? Also, what would be the best place to insert the btn_quest.off? Just after the displayGame() function inside the wakeUp() function?

Comment: Also, I can't seem to figure out where the btn_quest.off goes in the code. Can you please make a example using my wakeUp() function, to show me where I should put the btn_quest.off in my code?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. So, it's basically telling the program to switch it on, execute the things in the function, and switch it off, correct?

Comment: It has nothing to do with turning on and off. Think of on as ADD and off as REMOVE. You are adding multiple things. The first click is being called, followed by the second click. So the first click is still looking for bus/walk so it is the error. You need to get rid of that since it is done. So you remove it. To remove it you call off(). off removes all of the events applied to that element.

Comment: So, let me get this straight. It's like sending someone to buy bread. He goes there, and buys you bread and come back. Than, you send another guy to get milk. But the bread guy goes back to buy bread again, and comes back with bread, while the other guy is getting milk.  So I have a error. Correct?

Comment: No there is only one guy. You tell the guy to buy bread. He comes back and you tell him to buy milk. When he comes back he brings back another loaf of bread and a gallon of milk.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help. Speaking of which, I tried to enact your code snippet, but now it seems it doesn't work at all, etc no one gets bread or milk. What did I do wrong with my code? I'll add a edit in my main post to show you what I did.

Comment: `btn_quest.off("click").on; 
        "click", function() {` Because you used a semicolon....

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much. I get it now, and my code works. You are excellent, and played a fundamental part in my programming education. Goodnight and goodbye.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49426/discussion-between-user3367792-and-epascarello)